# How to make setItems working properly in SlickGrid?

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

I have this simple code:

```
var columnsTest = [ 
    {id: "testId", name: "ID", field: "id", width: 50},
    {id: "field1", name: "field1", field: "field1", width: 200},
    {id: "field2", name: "field2", field: "field2", width: 200}
]

function saveTest() {
    var itemFields = [];
    itemFields = dataViewTest.getItemById( dataViewTest.getItem(gridTest.getSelectedRows()).id );

    itemFields['field1'] =  $('#field1').val();
    itemFields['field2'] =  $('#field2').val(); 

    var data = JSON.stringify(itemFields);
    console.log("data: " + data);
    dataViewTest.beginUpdate();
    dataViewTest.setItems(itemFields, "id");
    dataViewTest.endUpdate();   
    dataViewTest.refresh(); 
}

$(function() {
    dialogTest = $( "#test_form" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 480,
        width: 600,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Save": function() { saveTest(); },
            "Cancel": function() { dialogCustomer.dialog( "close" ); }
        }
    });

    dataViewTest = new Slick.Data.DataView({ inlineFilters: true });

    gridTest = new Slick.Grid($("#test_grid"), dataViewTest, columnsTest, optionsTest);
    gridTest.setSelectionModel(new Slick.RowSelectionModel());
    gridTest.registerPlugin( new Slick.AutoTooltips({ enableForHeaderCells: true }) );
    pagerTest = new Slick.Controls.Pager(dataViewTest, gridTest, $("#test_pager"));

    dataViewTest.onRowsChanged.subscribe(function (e, args) {
      gridTest.invalidateRows(args.rows);
      gridTest.render();
    });         

    $( "#add_test" ).button().on('click', function() {
        dialogTest.dialog("option", "title", "Create New");
        dialogTest.dialog( "open" );
    }); 
});
```

where in console.log I have:

```
data: {"id":"187","field1":"aaaaaaa","field2":"bbbbbbb"}
```

but when I try to save console keeps saying: "Uncaught Each data element must implement a unique 'id' property"... shall I have missed something? 
Though i HAVE that id property and even passed to that objectIdProperty optional parameter of setItems...

thanks in advance! 
Cheers!
Luigi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how your function was even partially working before, because `gridTest.getSelectedRows()` returns an array and therefore `dataViewTest.getItem(selectedRows)` should error out. Also, since it appears as though you only want to update a single item, you would not be calling `dataViewTest.setItems()` because that is for updating multiple items at the same time and takes an array of objects/rows/items, not just one. This is probably what you want:

```
function saveTest() {
    var rows = gridTest.getSelectedRows(); // array of row indices: [5,8,21,42]
    var item = gridTest.getDataItem(rows[0]); // get the actual data item for the first selected row

    // update the properties for the item
    item.field1 = $('#field1').val();
    item.field2 = $('#field2').val(); 

    console.log("data:", item);

    // tell your dataview to update the item
    dataViewTest.updateItem(item.id, item);
}
```

Comment: Thanks idbehold... I was insisting with setItems() because I tought it was  ok also for only one row as the doc said about entire row and not the single cell... thanks again!